# kube-controller-manager & kube-apiserver questions for a kubeadm created cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I have created a k8s cluster using kubeadm and have a couple of questions about the kube-controller-manager and kuber-apiserver components.

- When created using kubeadm, those components are started as pods, not systemd daemons. If I kill any of those pods, they are restarted, but who is restarting them? I haven't seen any replicacontroller nor deployment in charge of doing that.
- What is the "right" way of updating their configuration? Imagine I want to change the authorization-mode of the api server. In the master node we can find a `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` folder with a `kube-apiserver.yaml` file. Are we supposed to change this file and just kill the pod so that it restarts with the new config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature you've described is called Static Pods. Here is a part of [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/static-pod/) that describes their behaviour.

> Static pods are managed directly by kubelet daemon on a specific node,
>   without the API server observing it. It does not have an associated
>   replication controller, and kubelet daemon itself watches it and
>   restarts it when it crashes. There is no health check. Static pods are
>   always bound to one kubelet daemon and always run on the same node
>   with it.
>
> Kubelet automatically tries to create a mirror pod on the Kubernetes
>   API server for each static pod. This means that the pods are visible
>   on the API server but cannot be controlled from there.
>
> The configuration files are just standard pod definitions in json or
>   yaml format in a specific directory. Use kubelet
>   `--pod-manifest-path=<the directory>` to start `kubelet` daemon, which periodically scans the directory and creates/deletes static pods as
>   yaml/json files appear/disappear there. Note that kubelet will ignore
>   files starting with dots when scanning the specified directory.
>
> When kubelet starts, it automatically starts all pods defined in
>   directory specified in `--pod-manifest-path=` or `--manifest-url=`
>   arguments, i.e. our static-web.

Usually, those manifests are stored in the directory `/etc/kubernetes/manifests`.
If you put any changes to any of those manifests, that resource will be adjusted just like if you would run `kubectl apply -f something.yaml` command.